# The proofs of a variant of Zorn's lemma

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, axiom-of-choice

On the basis of @drhab and @Michael comments, I have formalized two different proofs. Please have a check if these two proofs are fine. Thank you so much!

My variant:

> Suppose that $(A,\leq)$ is a partially ordered set in which each chain has an upper bound, and that $C$ is a chain in $A$. Then there exists a maximal $m$ of $A$ such that $c \leq m$ for all $c \in C$.

The proofs:

1. @drhab approach

> Let $T=\{D \subseteq A \mid  C \subseteq D \wedge D \text{ is a chain}\}$. Then $(T,\subseteq)$ is a partially ordered set.
>
> Assume $X$ is a chain in $T$. Let $Y=\cup_{x \in X}x$. Then $Y \in T$ and Y is an upper bound of $X$. As a result, $(T,\subseteq)$ satisfies condition of Zorn’s lemma. Hence $T$ has a maximal element $\bar{C}$.
>
> Let $m$ be an upper bound of $\bar{C}$. Then $m$ is also an upper bound of $C$.
>
> We now prove that $m$ is a maximal element of $A$. Assume $m < c$.
>   Then $\bar{C} \cup \{c\} \in T$ and $\bar{C} \subsetneq \bar{C} \cup \{c\}$. This contradicts the fact that $\bar{C}$ is a maximal element of $T$. As a result, $m \nless c$ for all $c \in A$.
>
> To sum up, $m$ is an upper bound of $C$ and a maximal element of $A$.

2. @Michael approach

> Let $u$ be an upper bound of $C$ and $T=\{x \in A \mid u \leq x\}$.
>
> Assume $X$ is a chain in $T$. Then $X$ has an upper bound in $T$.
>   As a result,  $(T,\leqslant)$ satisfies condition of Zorn’s lemma.
>   Hence $T$ has a maximal element $m$. $m \in T \implies m$ is an upper bound of $C$.
>
> We now prove that $m$ is a maximal element of $A$. Assume $m < c$. This contradicts the fact that $m$ is a maximal element of $T$. As a result, $m \nless c$ for all $c \in A$.
>
> To sum up, $m$ is an upper bound of $C$ and a maximal element of $A$.

Comment: Here is a generalization.  Instead of a chain, show for any not empty, A the upper set of A, { x : some a in A with a <= x }, has maximal points

Comment: Hi @WilliamElliot, I'm unable to get what you meant in "for any not empty, A the upper set of A, { x : some a in A with a <= x }, has maximal points". Please write it in a clearer and more precise term!

Comment: Hi @WilliamElliot,  a subset $U$ of a partially ordered set $(A,\leq)$ is call a upper set if for all $x \in U$ and $y \leq x$, then $y \in U$. Is this a correct definition of upper set?

Comment: No.  As above, the upper set of A = { x : some a in A with a <= x }.  If a in A and a <= x, then x in upper set.

Comment: Hi @WilliamElliot, I think your definition of upper set is different from those at https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Upper_set and at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/482622/question-about-the-definition-of-the-upper-set/482631. Can you elaborate on this difference? I'm very confused!

Comment: Hi @WilliamElliot, I seemed to find a counterexample of your proposed generalization. Let $A=\{\frac{-1}{n} \mid n \in \mathbb{N^*}\}$ and $B=\{-1\}$. Then the upper set of $B$ is $A$. But $A$ does not have any maximal point at all.

Comment: Thise definitions are the same as mine.  A does not have the property that every chain has an upper bound.

Comment: Is it true that, for your generalization to work, the universal set $A$ must have the property that every chain has an upper bound?

Comment: Yes, that is the orders we are discussing.